# $^n\sqrt{2^n-n^2} = ?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I think that $\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2} = 2$

I've tried to use the squeeze theorem for sequences:
i.e $\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2} \le \sqrt[n]{2^n} = 2$, but I couldn't find a lower bound.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: it is not so clear what you meant, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(2^n-n^2)^{1/n}$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}=\sqrt[n] {2^n}\cdot \sqrt[n]{1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}}=2\cdot \sqrt[n]{1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}}\to 2\cdot 1 =2$$

indeed

$$\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}}=e^{\frac{\log \left(1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}\right)}{n}}\to e^0=1$$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1 - \frac{n^2}{2^n} )^\frac{1}{n}=(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}1 - \frac{n^2}{2^n} )^\frac{1}{n}=(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}1 - \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{2^n} )^\frac{1}{n}=(1 - 0)^\frac{1}{n} = 1$

Comment: That’s not correct way to show thst, in a short way we can just observe that $1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}\to 1$ and $\frac 1 n\to 0$ then $$\left(1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}\right)^{\frac1n}\to 1^0=1$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\frac12\cdot2^{n}=2^{n-1}>n^2$ for large $n$.